# Stuck Installing Telegram on a Pi Zero W

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, pi-zero-w

Here's the steps I'm taking:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev libconfig-dev libssl-dev lua5.2 
liblua5.2-dev libevent-dev make  

git clone --recursive https://github.com/vysheng/tg.git && cd tg


./configure 
make
```

After the `make` command, I get this error (I've also tried `cd tg` before `make`, but I get the same error):

```
make: * * * No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I've tried attempting to start the program anyway with

```
cd tg
bin/telegram-cli -k tg-server.pub -W
```

But I get:

```
bash: bin/telegram-cli: No such file or directory
```

I've tried installing Telegram with `snap`, but it just pops up a help menu when I use `snap find | grep telegram`, and I've tried using a PPA repo but one doesn't exist for Raspbian. Any ideas?

**Edit**: Looks like this may be cause by the make command not finding a file called `Makefile`. From what I read, `./configure` is supposed to make this file. I ran `./configure` again, and the only error I get is:

```
checking for json_array_set_new in -ljansson... no configure: error: No libjansson found. Try --disable-json
```

Edit 2: Here's the results of running `./configure`

```
checking for gcc... gcc    
checking whether the C compiler works... yes     
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out     
checking for suffix of executables...      
checking whether we are cross compiling... no      
checking for suffix of object files... o     
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes     
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes     
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed      
checking for library containing clock_gettime... none required     
checking for library containing backtrace... none required     
checking for event_base_new in -levent... yes     
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E      
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep     
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E     
checking for ANSI C header files... yes     
checking for sys/types.h... yes      
checking for sys/stat.h... yes     
checking for stdlib.h... yes       
checking for string.h... yes      
checking for memory.h... yes     
checking for strings.h... yes      
checking for inttypes.h... yes     
checking for stdint.h... yes      
checking for unistd.h... yes     
checking event2/event.h usability... yes       
checking event2/event.h presence... yes       
checking for event2/event.h... yes       
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config      
checking whether compiling and linking against OpenSSL works... yes       
checking if zlib is wanted... yes       
checking for inflateEnd in -lz... yes      
checking zlib.h usability... yes      
checking zlib.h presence... yes     
checking for zlib.h... yes     
checking for rl_save_prompt in -lreadline... yes      
checking for libconfig... enabled     
checking for config_init in -lconfig... yes     
checking for liblua... enabled     
checking for lua... /usr/bin/lua      
checking if /usr/bin/lua is a Lua interpreter... yes     
checking for lua version... 5.2      
checking for lua platform... unknown       
checking for lua script directory... ${prefix}/share/lua/5.2        
checking for lua module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib/lua/5.2     
checking if LUA_VERSION is defined... yes      
checking lua.h usability... no      
checking lua.h presence... no      
checking for lua.h... no      
checking lualib.h usability... no     
checking lualib.h presence... no      
checking for lualib.h... no      
checking lauxlib.h usability... no      
checking lauxlib.h presence... no      
checking for lauxlib.h... no      
checking luaconf.h usability... no     
checking luaconf.h presence... no      
checking for luaconf.h... no     
checking for Lua headers in... /usr/include/lua5.2      
checking lua.h usability... yes    
checking lua.h presence... yes     
checking for lua.h... yes     
checking lualib.h usability... yes     
checking lualib.h presence... yes     
checking for lualib.h... yes     
checking lauxlib.h usability... yes      
checking lauxlib.h presence... yes     
checking for lauxlib.h... yes     
checking luaconf.h usability... yes     
checking luaconf.h presence... yes     
checking for luaconf.h... yes     
checking for Lua header version... 5.2     
checking if Lua header version matches 5.2... yes      
checking if LUA_VERSION is defined... yes      
checking for library containing exp... -lm      
checking for library containing dlopen... -ldl     
checking for library containing lua_load... -llua5.2     
checking for python... disabled       
checking for libjansson... enabled      
checking for json_array_set_new in -ljansson... no      
configure: error: No libjansson found. Try --disable-json
```

Comment: You have a clear error message. What is the question?

Comment: Saw that when I reran it after posting this, so now I have no earthly idea what that error means, and --disable-json doesn't do anything

Comment: The error "No libjansson found" means the library called Jansson (`libjansson`) is not installed on your system.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libjansson-dev`, then running `./configure` again, then `make` fixed it, I appreciate it

Comment: @techraf: that's the correct answer, but I can't meaningfully +1 a comment...

Answer (score 4):

The error "No libjansson found" means the library called [Jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/) (`libjansson`) is not installed on your system.

You need to install it (and you already figured out a correct way to do it yourself):

```
sudo apt-get install libjansson-dev
```